# exp concavity of hellinger loss

Tags: calculus, machine-learning

Let $\mathcal{Y} = \mathcal{D} = [0,1]$ and consider the Hellinger loss
\begin{equation}
    \ell(z, y) = \frac12 \left((\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{y})^2 + (\sqrt{1 - z} - \sqrt{1-y})^2 \right)
\end{equation}
Determine the values of $\eta$ for which the function $F(z) = e^{\eta\ell(z, l)}$ is concave.

Since this is a function in $1$ variable I can take the second partial derivative with respect to $z$ and find $\eta$ such that this second derivative is negative, but it ends up being intractable.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming $l \in [0,1]$. Break the functions up: let
$$f(z) = e^{\eta z/2} \qquad g(z) = (\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{l})^2 + (\sqrt{1-z} - \sqrt{1-l})^2 \qquad h(z) = f(g(z)).$$
Use the chain rule to compute
$$h''(z) = f'(g(z))g''(z) + f''(g(z))(g'(z))^2.$$
We have 2 observations that you should be able to verify:

1. $g(z)$ is convex in $[0,1]$.
2. $f(z)$ is convex.

Using these observations, conclude $h$ is convex if $\eta > 0$. (I have to check the concave case.) Looking at the functions in a graphing calculator of your choice (desmos) might help you.

Comment: for all $\eta$, $f''(z) > 0$ and thus it cannot be concave

Comment: It's still possible for $h$ to be concave, but the argument is more nuanced. I have to look at this problem more, but I plugged in the function into desmos and my hypothesis was corroborated. Regardless, if $\eta > 0$, $h$ is convex.

Comment: Basically, if $\eta$ is positive or sufficiently negative the Hellinger function is convex, but there is a neighborhood in the middle where it is concave, see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kwoazhvvgo